# Can I create a helper function to use with Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a helper function :

```
namespace PublicationSystem.Tools
{
    public class Format
    {
        public static string FullName(string salutation, 
            string first, 
            string middle, 
            string last, 
            string suffix = "")
        {
            var fullName = new StringBuilder();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(salutation)) fullName.Append(salutation + " ");

            fullName.Append(first + " ");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(middle)) fullName.Append(middle.Trim() + " ");

            fullName.Append(last);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(suffix)) fullName.Append(" " + suffix);

            return fullName.ToString().Trim();
        }
    }
}
```

I would love to use this in Linq queries, like this:

```
SessionUser = (
    from pi in db.ProfileIdentifier
    join p in db.Profile on pi.ProfileId equals p.ProfileId
    where
        pi.ProfileIdentifierTypeId == (int)ProfileIdentifierTypes.email &&
        pi.ProfileIdentifierValue == email &&
        pi.IsActive
    select new LoginViewModel
    {
        ProfileId = p.ProfileId,
        SessionId = sessionTokenId,
        FullName = Format.FullName(p.Salutation,p.FirstName,p.MiddleName,p.LastName),
        Email = email,
        Permissions = (
            from ra in db.RoleAssignment
            join rp in db.RolePermission on ra.RoleId equals rp.RoleId
            join perm in db.Permission on rp.PermissionId equals perm.PermissionId
            where ra.AssigneeId == p.ProfileId &&
                rp.IsActive
            select new ProfilePermission
            {
                RoleId = ra.RoleId,
                AssignedToId = ra.AssignedToId,
                PermissionId = perm.PermissionId,
                PermissionName = perm.PermissionName,
                PermissionGroupId = perm.PermissionGroupId
            }).ToList()
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but when querying against a datasource (e.g. SQL Server), that provider will not know what to do with your function.

You can use [.AsEnumerable()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb335435(v=vs.100).aspx) in a query to cause the rest of that query to be evaluated in the client rather than in the database.  After a call to .AsEnumerable(), you can use your own functions such as Format.FullName().

Note that you should avoid calling .AsEnumerable() before filtering is done that could be done in the database, as all data after that call are transported from the database to the client program.

Answer (score 0):

The [Linq To Sql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx) does not know how to parse the content of your method `FullName(..)` to sql.

You could execute your query returning an anonymous object, for sample:

```
var tempUser = (
    from pi in db.ProfileIdentifier
    join p in db.Profile on pi.ProfileId equals p.ProfileId
    where
        pi.ProfileIdentifierTypeId == (int)ProfileIdentifierTypes.email &&
        pi.ProfileIdentifierValue == email &&
        pi.IsActive
    select new 
    {
        p.ProfileId,
        SessionId = sessionTokenId,
        p.Salutation,       
        p.FirstName,
        p.MiddleName,
        p.LastName,
        Email = email
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

After, you could convert the result using your function `FullName(..)`, for sample:

```
if (tempUser != null)   
{
    SessionUser = new LoginViewModel
    {
        ProfileId = tempUser.ProfileId,
        SessionId = tempUser.SessionId,
        FullName = Format.FullName(tempUser.Salutation, tempUser.FirstName, tempUser.MiddleName, tempUser.LastName),
        Email = tempUser.Email
    };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the easiest conversion:

```
SessionUser = (
    from pi in db.ProfileIdentifier
    join p in db.Profile on pi.ProfileId equals p.ProfileId
    where
        pi.ProfileIdentifierTypeId == (int)ProfileIdentifierTypes.email &&
        pi.ProfileIdentifierValue == email &&
        pi.IsActive
    select p)
    .ToList()
    .Select(p=>new LoginViewModel
    {
        ProfileId = p.ProfileId,
        SessionId = sessionTokenId,
        FullName = Format.FullName(p.Salutation,p.FirstName,p.MiddleName,p.LastName),
        Email = email
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

This would be more efficient:

```
SessionUser = (
    from pi in db.ProfileIdentifier
    join p in db.Profile on pi.ProfileId equals p.ProfileId
    where
        pi.ProfileIdentifierTypeId == (int)ProfileIdentifierTypes.email &&
        pi.ProfileIdentifierValue == email &&
        pi.IsActive
    select p)
    .Take(1)
    .ToList()
    .Select(p=>new LoginViewModel
    {
        ProfileId = p.ProfileId,
        SessionId = sessionTokenId,
        FullName = Format.FullName(p.Salutation,p.FirstName,p.MiddleName,p.LastName),
        Email = email
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Even more efficient:

```
SessionUser = (
    from pi in db.ProfileIdentifier
    join p in db.Profile on pi.ProfileId equals p.ProfileId
    where
        pi.ProfileIdentifierTypeId == (int)ProfileIdentifierTypes.email &&
        pi.ProfileIdentifierValue == email &&
        pi.IsActive
    select new 
    {
        p.ProfileId,
        p.Salutation,       
        p.FirstName,
        p.MiddleName,
        p.LastName
    })
    .Take(1)
    .ToList()
    .Select(p=>new LoginViewModel
    {
        ProfileId = p.ProfileId,
        SessionId = sessionTokenId,
        FullName = Format.FullName(p.Salutation,p.FirstName,p.MiddleName,p.LastName),
        Email = email
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: That looks good. However, I added some code to my linq statement. I am doing a second/sub query. I'm wondering if I can do that still?

Comment: Using `ToList` here is a *very* bad idea.  At a *bare minimum* you should be using `AsEnumerable`, and even that isn't the best.

Comment: @MKenyonII Yes, you can still do that.  Just make sure to do the .Take(1) as well to limit the number of rows you return from the database to only 1.  Put your Permissions in the first select so it has access to the database, and add `Permissions=p.Permissions` in the second select.

Comment: Feel free to change the .ToList() to .AsEnumerable() as Servy suggested, although on my system the difference between the two is approximately 2/10000ths of a second +/- 1/10000ths of a second.  I would not classify that as a *very* bad idea, but it is better to use .AsEnumerable()